# gpg —list-keys command outputs uid [ unknown ] after importing private key onto a clean install

Tags: gpg, gnu

I did a clean install of Arch Linux and imported my backed up gpg private key. As a sanity check I ran:

```
gpg —list-keys
```

Everything showed up as normal except for the `uid` which now reads:

```
uid [ unknown ] User < user@useremail.com >
```

When I first created this key before the clean install it read:

```
uid [ ultimate ] User < user@useremail.com >
```

Why would it change from `[ ultimate ]` to `[ unknown ]`after importing it onto a clean install?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

GNUPG has a trust database stored at `~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg`

You can backup this trust database using the `--export-ownertrust` option:

```
gpg --export-ownertrust > file.txt
```

If you exported your secret keys and import them later into a new environment, the trust database is no longer present.

However, this is easily remedied:

```
gpg --edit-key user@useremail.com

gpg> trust

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 5
```

And don't forget to save the changes:

```
gpg> save
```

Read about trust [levels](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html) and [values](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Trust-Values.html). E.g. *unknown  Nothing is known about the owner's judgement in key signing. Keys on your public keyring that you do not own initially have this trust level*.

Comment: I keep getting ` gpg: can't do this in batch mode `

Comment: Minor note: it seems that `save` is not necessary, giving 'Key not changed so no update needed.'

Comment: I'm finding `save` is still very necessary. Without it I've been wondering why the ruddy hell my scripts to encrypt backups kept rejecting an encryption subkey. Time very wasted on my part!

Comment: If it doesn't seem to work with `gpg --edit-key user@useremail.com` (still says `[unknown]` when viewing `gpg --list-secret-keys`), try doing `gpg --edit-key` followed by the hex key, Ex. `0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567`. You also might have to restart gpg for changes to show: `Please note that the shown key validity is not necessarily correct unless you restart the program.`